# Select count for multiple dates

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have 3 tables: People, Group, and a PeopleGroup join table. PeopleGroup has a start and end date. Using linq-to-sql, I'm trying to write a query that will pull the count of group members on a 1-week interval for any given group over a specified date range. The end result would look something like (for group x in January):

```
Date        People Count
1/3/2009    445
1/10/2009   420
1/17/2009   426
1/24/2009   435
1/31/2009   432
```

Is that possible or do I need to write separate queries for each group/week combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to do something similar. After a little research I found that it would just be easier to process the data with c#.

In your situation, you could calculate a canonical date given a date in your data and group on that canonical date.

Comment: That's where I was headed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do in T-SQL. See if you can translate to LINQ speak.

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD (D, -1 * DATEPART (dw, DateTimeColumn), DateTimeColumn), 
    COUNT (*)
FROM DBO.UserTable
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD (D, -1 * DATEPART (dw, DateTimeColumn), DateTimeColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this. I don't know whether it works on LINQ to SQL but it works on LINQ to objects. First day of the week is sunday in this example but it can be changed.

```
        class Foo
        {
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        }

        var foos = new[] 
            {
                new Foo { Date = DateTime.Now },
                new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2009, 7, 3)},
                new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2009, 6, 20)},
                new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2009, 6, 21)},
                new Foo { Date = new DateTime(2009, 7, 2)}
            };

            var query = from foo in foos
                        group foo by foo.Date.AddDays(-(int)foo.Date.DayOfWeek) into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Count = g.Count(),
                            Date = g.Key
                        };

            foreach (var foo in query)
                Console.WriteLine("People count: {0} Date: {1}", foo.Count, foo.Date);
```

Comment: That would work if I had a set date on my records but I'm trying to get a count within a given begin-end range.